Expected value of Cosinus in High dimension
I would like to prove that the cosinus of the angle formed by 3 randomly points tends to $\frac{1}{2}$ as the dimensionality tends to $\infty$. Could it be solved with the expected value formula ? It would give :
$lim_{d\to\infty} \mathop{E}\left[\frac{(x-y)^T(x-z)}{\sqrt{(x-y)^T(x-y)}\sqrt{(x-z)^T(x-z)}}\right] = lim_{d\to\infty} \mathop{E}\left[\frac{\sum_{i=1}^d(x_i-y_i)(x_i-z_i)}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^d(x_i-y_i)(x_i-y_i)}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^d(x_i-z_i)(x_i-z_i)}}\right] = \frac{1}{2}$
with x,y,z random vectors (uniformly or gaussian distributed (it gives the same results in my empirical tests))
